# how can I manage controllers in Container View with using tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uicontainerview

On my storyboard I have main `ViewController`, not TabBarViewController, which consist of `TabBar` on the bottom, view on the top and `ContainerView` on the middle. `ContainerView` have a `NavigationController`. I also have 4 `ViewControllers`, one of them - `RootViewController` of `NavigationController`. I wish to show one of `ViewControllers` when I selecting TabBarItem, and in future I will add slide menu, which also will show selected ViewController.
I have next code, which only shows initial ViewController inside ContainerView, and when I selecting TabBarItems, new ViewControllers don't showing and I see only first View Controller. What goes wrong?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var first: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var second: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var third: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var fours: UITabBarItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var tabBar: UITabBar!

    var firstVC: FirstViewController?
    var secondVC: SecondViewController?
    var thirdVC: ThirdViewController?
    var foursVC: FoursViewController?

    var navi: UINavigationController?




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tabBar.delegate = self
        initialSetup()
    }

    func initialSetup() {

        tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items?.first

        navi = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "containerNavi") as? UINavigationController

        firstVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController") as? FirstViewController
        secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
        thirdVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController
        foursVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FoursViewController") as? FoursViewController
    }

    func showVC(number: Int) {
        switch number {
        case 0:
            navi?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
            print("0")
        case 1:
            if let second = secondVC {
                navi?.pushViewController(second, animated: true)
            }
            print("1")
        case 2:
            if let third = thirdVC {
                navi?.pushViewController(third, animated: true)
            }
            print("2")
        case 3:
            if let fours = foursVC {
                navi?.pushViewController(fours, animated: true)
            }
            print("3")
        default:
            return
        }
    }


}

extension ViewController: UITabBarDelegate {

    func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
        showVC(number: item.tag)
    }

}
```

Storyboard screenshot: [image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use this extesion to add/remove any of the 4 to containerView

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController, frame: CGRect? = nil) {
        addChildViewController(child)
        if let frame = frame {
            child.view.frame = frame
        }
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
    func remove() {
        willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParentViewController()

   }

}
```

// use it like this

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first")

self.add(vc, frame: self.containerView.frame)
```

to remove

```
vc.remove()
```

Comment: I adding this extension and trying to use method: if let second = secondVC, let first = firstVC {
                first.add(second, frame: second.view.frame)
            } , but it don't works

Comment: this code will be in FirstViewController? I want to call and dismiss controllers from main controller

Comment: you should use **self.add(first, frame: self.container.frame)** in the VC you posted it's code in the question , not add a child from another child , you have to remove the old child before adding a new one

Comment: it works, but for what I have container view? I will have UIView for use it.

Comment: use it like this? 
switch number {
        case 0:
            currentVC?.remove()
            currentVC = firstVC
            if let current = currentVC {
                self.add(current, frame: container.frame)
            }
        case 1:
            currentVC?.remove()
            currentVC = secondVC
            if let current = currentVC {
                self.add(current, frame: container.frame)
            }

Comment: It is not the best solution, but I use it