# How To Present New Controller on Already Presented Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

In my App i am Capturing image by custom camera. So at the time of capturing image i am presenting controller so it is showing camera in center and its looks like capturing image.
Here its code for that

```
    let layerVC = cameraLayerViewController(nibName: "cameraLayerViewController", bundle: nil)
            layerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

            Global.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(layerVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4, execute: {

                layerVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

but when changing camera mode i am presenting another controller on same controller

```
if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: Global.g_UserDefaultKey.isFrontCamera) as? Bool == true)
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: Global.g_UserDefaultKey.isFrontCamera)
        let controller : CameraVC = CameraVC(nibName: "CameraVC", bundle: nil)

        self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: Global.g_UserDefaultKey.isFrontCamera)
        let controller : CameraVC = CameraVC(nibName: "CameraVC", bundle: nil)
        self.present(controller, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

now when on this controller i am trying to present any controller its not working.

```
    let layerVC = cameraLayerViewController(nibName: "cameraLayerViewController", bundle: nil)
            layerVC.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

            Global.appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController?.present(layerVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4, execute: {

                layerVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

so let me know how can i present controller on already presented controller.

Comment: It would be helpful if you show a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve. Also you can explain what is not working. I will not downvote, because maybe it is me who just miss the point of the question, but I do suggest to simplify the question (write code that specifically asks the question instead of bringing code from your project, and make it the simplest as possible)

Comment: Try to use this, and let me know if it's help you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424511/how-can-i-manage-controllers-in-container-view-with-using-tab-bar

Answer (score 2):

To present the first view controller from the root:

```
let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
let firstPresented = FirstViewController()
firstPresented.transitioningDelegate = yourPresentationDelegate
firstPresented.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
root.present(firstPresented, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

To `present` the second view controller, you can't `present` from the root again since it's already presenting, so you must `present` from what is currently presented (which is `self`):

```
let secondPresented = SecondViewController()
secondPresented.transitioningDelegate = yourPresentationDelegate
secondPresented.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
self.present(secondPresented, animated: false, completion: nil)
```