# Adding a UITabbarController in appdelegate

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to add Tabbar to the application. But I don't know how to do this on AppDelegate. I want the code to be added in the Tabbar when maintableviewcontroller is opened. But I don't want the Tabbar to be added before the maintableviewcontroller opens. When I add Tabbar, the maintableviewcontroller always opens when I open the application. For example, when I exit the application, implementation with maintainleviewcontroller should not be opened. So how do I add tabbari to the maintableviewcontrols?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         FirebaseApp.configure()

         let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()
        tabBarController.delegate = self
        tabBarController.tabBar.shadowImage = UIImage(named: "transparent")
        tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "background_dark")

        let v1 = MainTableViewController()
        let v2 = NewMainTableViewController()
        let v3 = MainTableViewController()
        let v4 = ContactViewController()

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2 ) {
            v2.tabBarItem.badgeValue = "1"
        }

        v1.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleBouncesContentView(), title: "Anasayfa", image: UIImage(named: "homepage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "socket-4"))
        v2.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleBouncesContentView(), title: "Yeni Cihaz", image: UIImage(named: "socketmenu"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "energy"))
        v3.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleBouncesContentView(), title: nil, image: UIImage(named: "homepage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "homepage"))
        v4.tabBarItem = ESTabBarItem.init(ExampleBouncesContentView(), title: "İletişim", image: UIImage(named: "homepage"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "contactmenu-1"))


        tabBarController.viewControllers = [v1, v2, v3, v4]

        tabBarController.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatSand
        tabBarController.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let navigationControllerNew = ExampleNavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabBarController)


    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainTableViewController())
     // window?.rootViewController = navigationControllerNew

        window?.rootViewController = navigationController

        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Change your rootViewController according to your requirement , if you want tabBar then set tabbar as window. rootViewController or if you want any viewController then set it like window. rootViewController = AnyViewController

Comment: I don't want to set it as rootviewcontroller. AppDelegate view.I want an addSubview(tabbar).

Comment: then create a containerView and add tabbar to that.

Comment: I don't understand?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49424511/how-can-i-manage-controllers-in-container-view-with-using-tab-bar

Comment: I'd like to add it to AppDelegate.